# Const method - repeat in implementation?

Tags: c++, class, methods, constants

I've been searching a lot for an answer and can´t find it anywere. Say i have:

```
class foobar{
  public:
     char foo() const;
};
```

, in my foobar.h

When I want to implement this class in foobar.cpp should I repeat `const`?:

```
char foobar::foo() const{
//...my code
}
```

Or can i do (whitout the `const`)

```
char foobar::foo() {
//...my code
}
```

---

If this is a duplicate I'm sorry, but no other question truly answered this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you have to include the `const` qualifier in the definition.
If you write:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int f () const;
};
```

And in implementation file if you write:

```
int Foo::f () { /*...*/ }
```

then the compiler will emit an error saying that there is not function with signature `int f ()` in the class.
If you put the `const` keyword in your implementation file too, it will work.

It is possible to overload functions according to the object `const`ness.
Example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int foo ()       { std::cout << "non-const foo!" << std::endl; }
    int foo () const { std::cout << "const foo!" << std::endl; }
};

int main ()
{
    Foo f;
    const Foo cf;
    f.foo ();
    cf.foo ();
}
```

The output will be (as expected):

`non-const foo!`

`const foo!`

As we did with `const`, you can overload a function based on the object `volatile`ness too.

Comment: why would the output be different for the same operation?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote 'Foo cf' instead of 'const Foo cf' in the code. So with const objects, the const function will be called, with non-const objects, the non-const function will be called.

Answer (score 10):

You absolutely *must* include the `const` qualifier in the implementation.

It is possible to overload functions according to their `const`ness. In fact this is an important part of the language.

Comment: can you give me a reference link?

Comment: It's not definitive but http://www.cs.unm.edu/~storm/C++/ProgrammingTerms/FunctionSignatures.html might help. Or Google "function signatures".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because `const` is part of the signature. You can define two member functions that differ only in `const`-ness.

The easiest way to see that it is required is to test your code with your favorite compiler - the code below will not compile:

```
struct foobar{
    char foo() const;
};
char foobar::foo() {
    return 'a';
}
int main() {
    foobar().foo();
    return 0;
}
```

You should get an error similar to this:

> error: prototype for `'char foobar::foo()'` does not match any in class `'foobar'`
>
> ```
> char foobar::foo()
> ```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/RpL0v8)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should repeat `const`, it is part of the function signature. It is also possible to have another declaration and implementation without `const` modifier.

Comment: can you give me a reference link?

Answer (score 2):

If your variable is `char foo() const;` and you want to implement it you have to name it as same as you declared it.

```
char foobar::foo() const{
//...my code
}
```

`char foobar::foo();` is different to `char foobar::foo() const;`. It means you can have them both in your class declaration like :

```
class foobar{
  public:
     char foo() const;
     char foo();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, must need `const` qualifier in `foobar.cpp` file. when you use const in the method signature, you are telling the compiler that memory pointed to by `this` can't be changed by this method (which is `foobar` here).